# How to combine 2 iOS navigation-based apps?

Tags: ios

I currently have two navigation-based apps, call them MainApp and SecondApp. I'd like to put the SecondApp within the MainApp. Both apps compiled and ran on my computer. However, when I copy the SecondApp's class files into the MainApp it won't compile. Is there a more elegant way of doing this, or at least a way that actually works?

They error I'm getting is: "The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for RUnning the scheme..." Which is weird because BOTH apps ran on my computer prior to their merging.

EDIT: problem solved by created a new scheme (Product > New Scheme...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to Use Mac OS as the target. You should select an iOS version in the schemes drop down instead. This sometimes happens to me, and seems to be a bug in XCode 4.

If the option isn't in the schemes dropdown, see this link for how to fix it: [Xcode 4: My iPhone projects have become Mac OS projects.. and I can't change this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586675/xcode-4-my-iphone-projects-have-become-mac-os-projects-and-i-cant-change-this)